# How can I use REST Api to fetch local data in Angular

Tags: angular, rest, authentication

I am working on a task where I have to create a simple login page using REST Api. Username and password needs to be validated. I have created local JSON file with usernames and passwords stored in it. If the entered information in login fields matches then it should return success message.
I created UI and added Angular form validations in it. But I have no idea where to start in this task. Any help or guideline would be very helpful.

Comment: what you tried so far share your code so we will get the batter idea

Answer (score 3):

First You have to make form Validation see [Woking Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/material-login-form-with-validation-dz2frt?file=app/app.component.ts)

[see oficial site](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation)

then you have to make service to do rest calls (In Angular [HttpClient](https://angular.io/guide/http))

this is your json file * or you can call api URL

```
loginUrl = 'assets/config.json';

getLogin() {
  return this.http.get(this.loginUrl);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the best solution to this is using angular-in-memory-web-api. 
here is a link which explains it, just google for angular-in-memory-web-api and you should find more. Its quite easy to setup.
https://www.techiediaries.com/angular-inmemory-web-api/

i have a working example setup for this.
https://github.com/rahulz-wasnik/ng-travel-time-check.